# Grouping login/account functionality under a cart icon

Tags: login, e-commerce, accessibility, shopping-cart

I'm working on an commerce platform which needs account functionality | sign in/register | shopping bag/cart - standard stuff for such a website. The stakeholders are very keen to group all of that functionality into one icon, preferably under a cart icon in a pop out menu [Apple.com is the model they like], is this a good idea?

[I don't think it is but I'm open to being wrong] Apart from the fact that users might not be able to find their account/login/logout functionality, I'm wondering what the impact on accessibility would be.

I'm pushing for A|B testing . . .

Answer (score 2):

NOPE. Do not do that!

Its not at all a good signifier/affordance.

> **A good experience is all about "Expectation vs Outcome"**

When a user sees a cart icon, he **expects** to visit the summary of the cart. And when the **outcome** is indeed that, you have accomplished a great **seamless experience.**

But when he expects a cart and the outcome is account info, it leads to **"expectation-outcome mismatch"**. A very bad experience.

Comment: And of course, worst case scenario, do push for a A/B test. And ensure that each click is being tracked! So that you indeed will have data.

Answer (score 0):

A huge No, why would you want to group your account information under the cart icon. The cart icon is used to access your purchased items. I don't want a pop up to show when I clicked on the cart icon, I want it to take me to my purchased items and checkout. If you do that you risk losing customers when they are about to checkout.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE2mYx.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Use the user icon to group your account information.

Comment: Thanks for your comment/feedback - you have vindicated my point of view [which is really gratifying]. Unfortunately the business stakeholders that I am working with don't agree. I registered my objections with explanations, but to no avail, implementation is going ahead.